# Your project My First Project is being suspended for repeatedly violating our Google Cloud Platform Terms of Service or Acceptable Use Policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ios-app-suspended-state

How can i solve this issue?

[image]

I done two way authentication for security purpose
make communication between two instances using private Ip.
I even tried to reach support team to get the solution. he provide a link to get support from tech team. but i am redirected on the same page

Comment: Is this the first one you got, or is that "repeatedly violating..." referring something you've already received earlier?

Comment: Any luck or more information?